# Create a sub table row using ::after

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create a sub row for the last row in the table to look like in the photo, I'm on using pseudo-class in order to do, but the problem is I don't really know to to just the height of the tr in order to fit the newly class content.

```
<tr class="reject">
 <td class="semi-bold">2017</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">Montant principal : 700,00<br>
        Pénalité : 0<br>
        Majoration de retard : 100</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">Peugeot</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">000000B1</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">8 CV</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">800,00</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">
      <span class="state">
       <i class="state-suspended"></i>Rejeté
      </span>
    </td>
</tr>



.reject {
    position: relative;
}
.reject::after {

    content: "lol";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 11px;

}
```

This is what I want to get to:

[image]

This is where I am right now:

[image]

The entended table.

[image]

Comment: why use `position: absolute` instead of simply `display: block`?

Comment: it doesn't work using a display block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things: the content of the cells you want to be aligned to the top of the cell, not central; the pseudo element needs to be placed after the other content so it can go at top: 100%.

```css
.reject {
  position: relative;
}

.reject::after {
  content: "lol";
  position: absolute;
  rbottom: 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 11px;
}

.reject td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="reject">
    <td class="semi-bold">2017</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">Montant principal : 700,00<br> Pénalité : 0<br> Majoration de retard : 100</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">Peugeot</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">000000B1</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">8 CV</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">800,00</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">
      <span class="state">
       <i class="state-suspended"></i>Rejeté
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's really great, the problem is when adding a new tr under this one then we have a problem.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, I thought it was the last row. What is the situation? Could you put  a bit more code into your question to show how you add further rows and what you want it to look like when it's not the last tr. Thanks.

Comment: look at the edit, whenever the status is red (i.e rejected), there should be a text under it indicating why it was rejected. the table has a lot of tr.

Comment: THe edit still shows that it's the last row that is rejete so I'm sorry I don't understand. Can there be several such rows? Or can the rejected one be anywhere but the red message is to be at the bottom of the table? Or is the red message to be immediately under any reected row?

Comment: this is just the mockup I got, but there can be hundreds of rows and if the status of that row is rejected ( red ) there should be a message under it. Only on the rejected ones, and there are ordered by date so the rejected ones can be anywhere.

Comment: That is why I created a class specifically for the rejected ones in order to give them that message. and not disturb the other rows.